# Defined or undefined integral

Tags: integration, complex-integration, riemann-integration

Suppose, I want to calculate $$I = \int\limits_{0}^1 (-1)^x dx.$$

Indeed, I'm not that good at integration, so I try to express $-1$ in some "simpler" way, like $$-1 = e^{i \cdot \pi}.$$

Then, integrating is pretty technical and I get $$I = \frac{2i}{\pi}.$$

But, otherwise I could pick just any other representation of $-1$, like $$-1 = e^{i \cdot (\pi + 2n\pi)}, \qquad n \in \mathbb{Z},$$ and the result would change accordingly to $$I = \frac{2i}{(2n+1)\pi}.$$

Now, my question is: does this mean that the integral is undefined, or is it defined but only when we pick the specific branch of $(-1)^z$ and what are those branches?

Comment: You already nailed the problem. $(-1)^x$ is undefined over the real numbers. Over the complex numbers it involves the complex logarithm, and that is multi-valued.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is exactly as you've identified: $(-1)^x$ isn't well-defined for generic real numbers.

> Now, my question is: does this mean that the integral is undefined, or is it defined but only when we pick the specific branch of $(−1)^z$ and what are those branches?

There is a potential difference between what is *meant* and what is *written*. If someone simply asked me if $(-1)^x$ is integrable over $[0, 1]$, and gave me no additional context, then I would say "no".

If you specify a particular branch (which amounts to choosing the $n$ in your question), then that is a different question entirely. Any particular choice of branch leads to an integrable function. Distinguishing between branches is a confusing problem.